# how to pack list into string in python

Tags: python

I am new to programming and python trying to figure out how to pack list and get a string value out of it? and can also determine the size of the list it should be of 4bytes
can someone suggest a way to do it.

```
      hello=[1,2,3,4]
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want the size of the list in bytes, and not the cardinality of the list?

Comment: yes I have IP address ip = 192,168,0,1 this integer should be converted into string and then i will take hash sha1 of that string value as hash does not accept integer...

Comment: `hashlib.sha1(".".join([192,168,0,1])).hexdigest()`. But a list is not the ideal way to store an IP address...

Comment: Oh, and if you want the SHA1 of the IP in its binary format, try this: `hashlib.sha1(struct.pack("!BBBB", *[192, 168, 1, 5])).hexdigest()`. Note the `!` in the argument to `struct.pack`, that means "network byte order".

Comment: @cha0site: Byte order is sublimely irrelevant when there is only one byte to order.

Comment: @John: Too true. But better reinforce the notion that "Hey, I'm dealing with a network here! I need to use *network* *byte* *order*!"

Comment: Thank you very much for you help its working so for my understanding it is taking list as Binary? taking sha1.hex out of it?

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what you want, instead of replying in comments.

Comment: @Shazib: Yes, my second example is transforming the list into a binary representation. See my edited answer below.

Answer (score 3):

See Dor's answer for one solution, more solutions for making strings out of lists are:

```
repr([1,2,3,4])
```

and:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint([1,2,3,4])
```

---

## Hashing an IP address with SHA1

Assuming that each octet is stored as an element of the list.

This one converts the IP address to a string, like `192.168.0.1`, and hashes that.

```
hashlib.sha1(".".join([192,168,0,1])).hexdigest()
```

While this one converts the IP address to a packed binary format, 4 bytes long, and hashes *that*.

```
hashlib.sha1(struct.pack("!BBBB", *[192, 168, 1, 5])).hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 3):

Getting size:

```
from sys import getsizeof
getsizeof([1,2,3,4]) # 48 on my computer
```

For containers it can be a bit trickier in general. Please refer to this code snippet for how to do it:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504/

Getting a string from a list is a little bit unclear, try:

```
repr([1,2,3,4]) # "[1, 2, 3, 4]"
```

or even

```
', '.join(str(i) for i in [1,2,3,4]) # "1, 2, 3, 4"
```

Comment: Given the apparent level of the author, and the fact he said "it should be of 4bytes", I'm pretty sure he's thinking of len and imagining one byte per number, and not getsizeof.

Comment: Ah, you're probably right. Not going to add another edit though :)

Answer (score 2):

str.join() requires an iterator of strings, so you have to convert it

```
','.join(map(str, [1,2,3,4]))
```

or

```
','.join(str(i) for i in [1,2,3,4])
```

Comment: map is less clear and sometimes slower (see http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops as a reference) than a list comprehension.

Comment: In that second example, is that a list comprehension or a generator? I thought list comprehensions use square brackets and generators use parens, but here there's neither.

Comment: @darkporter That would be a generator expression, the normal brackets are implied. It would function exactly the same as with a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to pack a list (whose length is known to be a small constant, e.g. 4, and whose elements are all unsigned integers less than 256) into a string as one byte per list element:

Packing:

```
>>> hello = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> import struct
>>> pkd = struct.pack("4B", *hello)
>>> pkd
'\x01\x02\x03\x04'
```

Unpacking:

```
>>> struct.unpack("4B", pkd)
(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> list(struct.unpack(">4B", pkd))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Packing a list of unknown length:

```
>>> pkd = ''.join(chr(i) for i in hello)
>>> pkd
'\x01\x02\x03\x04'
```

Unpacking:

```
>>> [ord(c) for c in pkd]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where the string you are calling `join()` from is the delimiter:

```
",".join([str(item) for item in [1,2,3,4]])
```

This produces "1,2,3,4".

The list comprehension is the clearest method of doing this, and [in most cases the fastest](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops).

As to the size of the list in bytes - what you really want to do is use `len()` on the list and check it is 4. Obviously, in Python, ints can be far larger than a byte, so, if needed, check that each value applies 0 => x => 255.